# Magento Customer Attributes Import/Export

Tags: magento, import, export, magento-1.9, magento-1.9.1

I've added a custom attribute to the customer account i Magento. It's a multiselect attribute.
When I export customers to cvs via dataprofiles the attribute is present in the CSV with ids separated by commas i.e "13,14".
When I try to import customers with the multiselect attribute Magento gives me following error:

> File is totally invalid. Please fix errors and re-upload file
>   Checked rows: 1, checked entities: 1, invalid rows: 1, total errors: 1

The error relates to the column with my custom attribute.

How do i remedy this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try multiselect attributes with below format

```
[data][space][comma][space][data][space]...
```

So for your example:

```
13 , 14
```